# Faster Alternative to numpy.unique

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to find unique pixels in a numpy ndarray of shape 400, 800, 3. I can get exactly what I want with `np.unique(im.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0)` however np.unique is too slow for my application because it sorts the array. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46575580/13471744) answer which seems to offer a faster alternative. However, because it flattens the array, it gives unique single integers, rather than unique RGB color values. How can I get unique rgb values with numpy?

Comment: You can achieve this by converting the 3D RGB ndarray to a 1D array with 24-bit integers representing the colors, using the faster method, and then converting the 24-bit integers back to RGB values. You can also try to make a [view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) of the original array that treats each RGB triplet as a single element, but I'm not familiar enough with views to provide a definitive example.

Comment: Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65680786/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59671950/2836621

Comment: If you are not intereseted in sorted restults and able to use `pandas` then I'd suggest having a look at [pandas.unique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) which is a lot faster!

Comment: @RandomDavis But 24 bits is 16 million possibilities, much more than their 320,000 pixels. (Of course it *might* still be faster, but I find that doubtful.)

Comment: How slow is np.unique, how fast do you need it, and how many unique pixels do you have?

Comment: @KellyBundy When converting the 3D RGB ndarray to a 1D array with 24-bit integers representing the colors, we are not increasing the total number of possibilities - there are still the same number of RGB color combinations. Each 24-bit integer represents one of 16 million possible color combinations (256 possibilities per channel: 256 x 256 x 256 = 16,777,216), but there are still only 320,000 pixels in our image regardless of the format used. We are not expanding the bit depth of each channel to 24 bits; rather, we are combining the three 8-bit channels (R, G, B) into a single 24-bit integer.

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes, but that other method turns possibilities into actual memory (its `q` array would have size 2^24). Did you actually read it?

Comment: @KellyBundy What `q` array are you referring to? Please provide more context or point to the relevant part of the discussion where it was mentioned. Why do you think that converting the 3D RGB ndarray to a 1D array with 24-bit integers would create extra memory usage? The proposed method doesn't seem to expand the search space, as the goal is to represent the same data more efficiently.

Comment: @RandomDavis `q` is from the answer / faster method that they linked to. What other faster method were you talking about instead?

Comment: @KellyBundy I missed that.

Comment: @KellyBundy Since we are checking for unique triplets of 8-bit values, why would the memory footprint be any different? There's still the exact same number of unique possibilities for 24-bit values as there are trios of 8-bit values.

Comment: @RandomDavis Not sure what you mean, but it sounds like you don't understand that other method. Do you see why its `q` would have size 2^24? And do you see that 400*800 is far less?

Comment: What's your array's dtype?

Comment: And what's the range of values in the array?

Comment: @KellyBundy the array's dtype is uint8. After profiling the script, 33 seconds out of the total 50 seconds of runtime are spent in np.sort due to np.unique's implementation. I don't care about sorting, so this is a huge waste of time for my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard `set` will be the fastest:

```py
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randint(0, 256, (400, 800, 3))

t1 = timeit("u = np.unique(x.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0)", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit(
    "xt = x.reshape(-1, 3).T;pd.Series(zip(xt[0], xt[1], xt[2])).unique()",
    number=1,
    globals=globals(),
)
t3 = timeit(
    "u = set(zip(x.flat[::3], x.flat[1::3], x.flat[2::3]))", number=1, globals=globals()
)
t4 = timeit(
    "l1, l2, l3 = x.flat[::3].tolist(), x.flat[1::3].tolist(), x.flat[2::3].tolist();u = set(zip(l1, l2, l3))",
    number=1,
    globals=globals(),
)

print(f"np.unique      {t1:>10.3f}")
print(f"pd.Series      {t2:>10.3f}")
print(f"set            {t3:>10.3f}")
print(f"tolist() + set {t4:>10.3f}")
```

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700x):

```
np.unique           0.233
pd.Series           0.117
set                 0.058
tolist() + set      0.040
```

Comment: yes, but then you have a `set`... not a `numpy.array`... conversion to numpy will be more expensive than what you gain

Comment: @raphael Yes, if the `set` is converted back to numpy array (e.g. `np.fromiter(s, dtype=(np.int8, 3), count=len(s))` where `s` is the unique set) then the performance is the same as `np.unique`)

Comment: @KellyBundy I'll edit an answer, that depends on how many uniques are in the `set`

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, you're right! I've just rewritten the tests using `timeit.timeit`. Then `tolist() + set` method is fastest.

Comment: Ok, that's even better. Includes each method's destruction time, which is the realistic thing to do. I also just tried with `tobytes` instead of `tolist`. Surprisingly it was slower, but when I changed your input array's dtype to `uint8` (which seems likely), it was faster, as hoped.

Comment: Oh wait, I misremembered. The timeit template takes start/end time *inside* the function. [Link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a1026077af65b308c98cdfe181b5f94c46fb48a/Lib/timeit.py#L69). So the last destruction (due to `number=1` the *only* one) isn't included in the time. Probably gives the `set` solutions an unfair advantage, since their destruction is likely more costly.

Answer (score 1):

A (very) quick check between `numpy` and `pandas` shows that even with all required conversions `pandas.unique` outperforms `numpy` if sorting is not a concern.

Here's how this could work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

x = np.random.randint(0, 256, (400, 800, 3))


tic = timeit.default_timer()
uniques = np.unique(x.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0)
toc = timeit.default_timer()
print("numpy", toc-tic)

tic = timeit.default_timer()
xt = x.reshape(-1, 3).T
uniques = pd.Series(zip(xt[0], xt[1], xt[2])).unique()
toc = timeit.default_timer()
print("pandas", toc-tic)
```

```
>>> numpy 0.31687320000492036
>>> pandas 0.22542680002516136
```